# How to remove the sent message's border in Contact Form 7 and make the whole message disappear after 5 sec?

Tags: forms, border, contacts

the title is my question. Could you please show me the coding instead of telling me how to do as I have no idea how to code. Thanks a million.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output / tracebacks). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Solved the border part. 
.wpcf7 .wpcf7-form .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok { 
 display: none !important; 
}

Comment: Please add your code by editing your question instead of adding it as a comment. Thank you.